# Automorphism induced automorphism of Lp spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure.  If $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a homeomorphism, then does $\Phi$ induce a homeomorphism of the Bochner-Lebesgue space $L^p_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ onto itself by
$$
f\mapsto \Phi^{-1}\circ f\circ\Phi?
$$

Comment: No. Take $d=1$, let $\mu(dx) = e^{-x^2}dx$, let $f(x)=e^x$, and let $\Phi(x) = x^3$. Notice that $f \in L^p(\mu)$ for all $1\le p < \infty$. However $(\Phi^{-1}f\;\Phi)(x) = e^{\frac13 x^3} $ which is never in any $L^p(\mu)$.

Comment: I will accept this answer if you put it :)